# HttpSession is not returning a null session in JSP?

Tags: jsp

I want to enter my page only when I provide proper authentications but I am able to access the page with the URL of the page as well. Please check the mistake

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%
if(request.getSession(false)!=null) {   
    String name=(String)session.getAttribute("name");
    String path=(String)session.getAttribute("dp_path");
    String profile_id=(String)session.getAttribute("profile_id");

%>

%html%

<%
} 
else {
        out.println("<font color=red size=4>You are not Logged In</font><br>Please "
            + "<a href=index.jsp>login</a> to access this page"); 
}
%>
```

What should I do to make it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the user is authenticated. Not that there is a session. Those two facts are unrelated: you can have a session even if the user is not authenticated.

Put some information in the session after authentication to distinguish sessions of authenticated visitors from sessions of non-authenticated visitors.

Comment: JB Nizet: If i access the page with its url without logging-in then the page should not be accessed but i am able to enter the page.I want that if i enter the url of the page then the else part of the code should run.

Comment: And my answer tells you how to do. Understand that the session is not created wen the user authenticates. A session is created as soon as the user, even unauthenticated, visits a JSP page (or getSession() is explicitely called).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code  below

```
<%
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String name=(String)session.getAttribute("name");
String path=(String)session.getAttribute("dp_path");
String profile_id=(String)session.getAttribute("profile_id");

if(name!=null) {   
%>
```